# Why is Tensorflow running slower on GPU then on CPU?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a problem regarding running a script using my GPU instead of CPU.
[Time on GPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzLMl.jpg)
[Task Manager consumption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJBVt.jpg)

The CSV file is pretty small, having 15 MB size.

I'm running on a GTX 2060 Laptop

I've tried many things until now but seems to behave the same.

I'm pretty sure that I'm using correctly the GPU but I don't think it should take like 10% more than running on CPU. Can you please help me?

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1337)  # for reproducibility

from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Lambda
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras.layers import Convolution1D,MaxPooling1D, Flatten
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras import backend as K
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical

from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution1D, Dense, Dropout, Flatten, MaxPooling1D
from keras.utils import np_utils
import numpy as np
import h5py
from keras import callbacks
from keras.layers import LSTM, GRU, SimpleRNN
from keras.callbacks import CSVLogger
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau, CSVLogger
from sklearn.metrics import (precision_score, recall_score,f1_score, accuracy_score,mean_squared_error,mean_absolute_error)
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder


traindata=pd.read_csv('UNSW_NB15_training-set.csv',skiprows=1,names=['id','dur','proto','service','state','spkts','dpkts','sbytes','dbytes','rate','sttl','dttl','sload','dload','sloss','dloss','sinpkt','dinpkt','sjit','djit','swin','stcpb','dtcpb','dwin','tcprtt','synack','ackdat','smean','dmean','trans_depth','response_body_len','ct_srv_src','ct_state_ttl','ct_dst_ltm','ct_src_dport_ltm','ct_dst_sport_ltm','ct_dst_src_ltm','is_ftp_login','ct_ftp_cmd','ct_flw_http_mthd','ct_src_ltm','ct_srv_dst','is_sm_ips_ports','attack_cat','label'])
testdata=pd.read_csv('UNSW_NB15_testing-set.csv',skiprows=1,names=['id','dur','proto','service','state','spkts','dpkts','sbytes','dbytes','rate','sttl','dttl','sload','dload','sloss','dloss','sinpkt','dinpkt','sjit','djit','swin','stcpb','dtcpb','dwin','tcprtt','synack','ackdat','smean','dmean','trans_depth','response_body_len','ct_srv_src','ct_state_ttl','ct_dst_ltm','ct_src_dport_ltm','ct_dst_sport_ltm','ct_dst_src_ltm','is_ftp_login','ct_ftp_cmd','ct_flw_http_mthd','ct_src_ltm','ct_srv_dst','is_sm_ips_ports','attack_cat','label'])


for column in traindata.columns:
    if traindata[column].dtype == type(object):
        le = LabelEncoder()
        traindata[column] = le.fit_transform(traindata[column])

for column in testdata.columns:
    if testdata[column].dtype == type(object):
        le = LabelEncoder()
        testdata[column] = le.fit_transform(testdata[column])

X = traindata.iloc[:,1:44]
Y = traindata.iloc[:,44]
C = testdata.iloc[:,44]
T = testdata.iloc[:,1:44]

scaler = Normalizer().fit(X)
trainX = scaler.transform(X)

scaler = Normalizer().fit(T)
testT = scaler.transform(T)

y_train = np.array(Y)
y_test = np.array(C)

X_train = np.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0],trainX.shape[1],1))
X_test = np.reshape(testT, (testT.shape[0],testT.shape[1],1))

lstm_output_size = 70

cnn = Sequential()
cnn.add(Convolution1D(64, 3, padding="same",activation="relu",input_shape=(43, 1)))
cnn.add(Convolution1D(64, 3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
cnn.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(2)))
cnn.add(Convolution1D(128, 3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
cnn.add(Convolution1D(128, 3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
cnn.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(2)))
cnn.add(LSTM(lstm_output_size))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.1))
cnn.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))


cnn.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam",metrics=['accuracy'])

# train
checkpointer = callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath="checkpoint-{epoch:02d}.hdf5", verbose=1, save_best_only=True, monitor='val_acc',mode='max')
csv_logger = CSVLogger('cnntrainanalysis1.csv',separator=',', append=False)

cnn.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1000,validation_data=(X_test, y_test),callbacks=[checkpointer,csv_logger])
cnn.save("cnn_model.hdf5")
```

Comment: 10% more what?  How are you measuring the performance?

Comment: 10% more time. I run the script 2 times on CPU and time was 10% lower than the one using GPU

Comment: Measured how?  Performance measurement is an art form.

Comment: when using bigger sized networks, the GPU version performs much better than the CPU version. I suspect this is due to overhead coming from loading data into GPU memory. Thanks!